# Zombie SharedDataMiddleware on Python Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I'm setting up a Flask app on Heroku. Everything is working fine until I added static files. I'm using this:

```
from werkzeug import SharedDataMiddleware
app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = SharedDataMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, {'/static': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static') })
```

The first time I deploy the app, the appropriate files in the ./static will be available at herokuapp.com/static. But after that initial deploy, the files never change on Heroku. If I change the last line to:

```
app.wsgi_app = SharedDataMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, {'/assets': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static') })
```

a new URL for the static files, herokuapp.com/assets, then I can see the updated files.

It seems like a mirror of the files gets stuck in the system. I've changed it four times and can access all of the URLs still.

Comment: Why you don't use the part of flask which handels static files for you? It's well described in the [Flask Docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#static-files).

Comment: It's also well documented as not working well in production environments. SharedDataMiddleware is the way to go here. Just can't figure out why it's stuck in Heroku's system.

Comment: @nathancahill, serving static files with Flask is not *recommended* in production because a server like nginx is faster at it than going through Python. But SharedDataMiddleware is Python and thus no better than Flask.

Comment: Oh, I guess that would make sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SharedDataMiddleware defaults to sending `Cache-Control` and `Expires` HTTP headers, which means that your web browser may not even send a request to the server and just use the old files from cache. Try [disabling the cache](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/middlewares/):

```
app.wsgi_app = SharedDataMiddleware(
    app.wsgi_app,
    {'/static': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')},
    cache=False)
```

Flask does the same with static files. To [disable it](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/) there:

```
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = None
```

Comment: Works, but I ended up just putting all my static files on S3.