# Serving static html pages with flask on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask

Im trying to figure out how to serve static pages from heroku with a flask app. I found this with some searching:

```
@app.route('/foo/<path:filename>')
def send_foo(filename):
     return send_from_directory('/path/to/static/files', filename)
```

But, this would be quite inefficient. Is there a way to have the front facing server directly serve these files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515804/zombie-shareddatamiddleware-on-python-heroku

I got that to work.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would do this with mod_rewrite with apache or similar, but afaik heroku doesn't let's you change the http server configuration.

You'll need to use the rack middleware, it lets you write url rewrite rules with ruby. (check this out : http://icelab.com.au/articles/useful-heroku-friendly-rewrites-with-rack-rewrite/ )

Comment: Hm... Interesting. But I would keep this as a last last last resort, as it would add another layer of application nesting. The only reason Im creating a flask app is to auto deploy a pelican app

Comment: Oops forget the ruby code.. just noticed that you're using python. There's nothing much you can do about this, you have to route the request from within your application. Your current implementation seems fine to me.